# Moondroid Coverflow: Slow down scroll speed

Tags: android, android-animation, coverflow

I'm using [Moondroid Coverflow](https://github.com/moondroid/CoverFlow)  in my project, but the scrolling speed is way too high. I swipe a little and the carousel turns way too much.

Is there any solution to this or do I have to switch to another coverflow?

Single Page Pagination would be fine too.

Comment: Try FancyCoverFlow lib that lib have many option. Just search on google for that lib you can found the solution for your issue.

Comment: @AndyDeveloper are there any useful tutorials for FancyCoverFlow? Do you have any experience with [link](https://github.com/applm/CarouselWidget)?

Comment: Yup I have experience with this lib but as I implemented the FancyCoverFlow it fit to my requirement but you can use the CarouselWidget which you provide in the link.

Comment: @AndyDeveloper Thanks for your answer. Do you know of any tutorial for FancyCoverFlow?

Comment: Here is the tutorial you can [refer this](https://github.com/davidschreiber/FancyCoverFlow)

Comment: @AndyDeveloper Is there somewhere a tutorial? I only see the small "how to use?" section at the end. I'm a beginner in android programming, and I'm hoping for a little more guidance.

Answer (score 1):

After searching for hours finally found a workaround/solution! It's pretty simple, I know probably nobody's going to use this library again, but you never know you may need it sometime!

So, basically, [Moondroid CoverFlow](https://github.com/moondroid/CoverFlow) itself forked from another repository of applm's [ma-components](https://github.com/applm/ma-components).

Step 1: So what you need to do is import that repository (applm's ma-components) into your project as a library. So that you can directly make changes in the code for CoverFlow!

Step 2: After importing the library open EndlessLoopAdapterContainer from com.martinappl.components.ui.containers!

Step 3: Find the fling method inside that Adapter, it should be something like this:

```
public void fling(int velocityX, int velocityY){
    mTouchState = TOUCH_STATE_FLING;
    final int x = getScrollX();
    final int y = getScrollY();
    mScroller.fling(x, y, velocityX, velocityY, Integer.MIN_VALUE,Integer.MAX_VALUE, Integer.MIN_VALUE,Integer.MAX_VALUE);

    invalidate();
}
```

Now just add the following line before calling mScroller.fling():

```
velocityX *= 0.1; //change the float value as per your need, a lesser value will slow down the scroll speed
```

And that's it, you've successfully slowed down the scroll speed of the CoverFlow!